# Skip Zero Value Rows on Bar Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a table of values that is similar to this:

```
Fruit   Qty
Apples  5  
Oranges 2  
Bananas 0  
Peaches 1
```

When I create a bar chart I only want those rows with positive values to be displayed, in this case it would only show the three bars for Apples, Oranges, and Peaches, skipping Bananas.

I have seen how to do this in a Stacked Bar Chart, but that's not what I want. The chart can either be horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Advanced Filter`, for example in column E, in `E1` write `QTY`, in `E2`write `>0`
Your Data in A1:B5 select it Click Data, Advanced, in list Range you will have `$A$1:$B$5` and Criteria Range `$E$1:$E$2` your Data will be filtered for Qty >0 and you can Insert your Chart by selecting the filtered Data, it will look like the picture below.[image: The Chart]